# Double dispatch in Scala

Tags: scala

In java, we use a double dispatch for visitor pattern. Scala can use pattern matching to solve it since it is super powerful. I just wonder is there a good double dispatch example in Scala or it is very bad, because exposing references to each other is not a good idea

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Martin Odersky [says](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/pattern_matching.html): "The visitor pattern [...] can represent some of the things we do with pattern matching in an object-oriented way, based on virtual method dispatch. But in practical use the visitor pattern is very bulky. You can't do many of the things that are very easy with pattern matching. You end up with very heavy visitors. And it also turns out that with modern VM technology it's way more inefficient than pattern matching. For both of these reasons, I think there's a definite role for pattern matching."

Comment: I've done my own benchmarking and can confirm that pattern matching usually outperforms the visitor pattern, while being much more readable - the visitor pattern is almost an anti-pattern in Scala. The other alternative is to use type-classes, which can be even more extensible at the cost of some boiler-plate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call the correct method in Scala/Java based the types of two objects without using a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580560/how-to-call-the-correct-method-in-scala-java-based-the-types-of-two-objects-with)