# Scala polymorphic overloaded method dispatch results in StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, polymorphism, overloading, hierarchy, traits

Learning Scala by playing with object hierarchy and came up with the following:

```
trait LogItem {
  override def toString = getClass.getName
}

class LogItemOne extends LogItem {}

class LogItemTwo extends LogItem {}

class LogService {
  private def addLogItem(item: LogItemOne) = { println(item.toString) }
  private def addLogItem(item: LogItemTwo) = { println(item.toString) }

  def addLogItem[A <: LogItem] (item: A): Unit = { addLogItem(item) }
}
```

The following test causes `StackOverflowError`

```
"Log service" should "polymorphically add log item" in {
    new LogService().addLogItem(new LogItemOne())
    new LogService().addLogItem(new LogItemTwo())
}
```

Is it possible to polymorphically dispatch to the right `addLogItem` method without the clients of `LogService` having to call a specific method for a specific type of `LogItem`?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Scala does not perform dynamic dispatch on the method parameter (same as Java). In other words, your code would not polymorphically choose the correct method for the given `LogItem`. Instead, since `A` erases to `LogItem`, it would recursively call `addLogItem[A <: LogItem](item: A)` again, which leads to the `StackOverflow`.

A way to "fake" dynamic dispatch on the parameter would be to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). However, in this case, the best solution is probably to use Scala's powerful `match` statement:

```
class LogService {
  private def addLogItemOne(item: LogItemOne) = { println(item.toString) }
  private def addLogItemTwo(item: LogItemTwo) = { println(item.toString) }

  def addLogItem(item: LogItem): Unit = item match {
    case one: LogItemOne => addLogItemOne(one)
    case two: LogItemTwo => addLogItemTwo(two)
  }
}
```

Comment: The `case` above is just a glorified `if-else`. I'm aware of the visitor pattern, which means every `LogItem` would have an `accept(v: LogItemVisitor) { v.visit(this) }` and a `LogItemVisitor` implementation would have the overloaded `visit` methods. I thought if we could do that, we might be able to do what I showed in my example too. Apparently not.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The problem in your code is really just that the method that is invoked is chosen based on the static type of `item`. It may be a bit confusing since you gave all three methods the same name, but method overloading really just creates an independent (different) method with the same name. So yeah, to the best of my knowledge there's no out of the box mechanic that gives you dynamic dispatch based on the parameter type.

Comment: I understand but if I named the methods differently, like in your example, I'd have to know the argument type, which's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar My point is, that it does not matter whether the methods have the same name or not, because dispatch happens based on the static type, i.e., the type must be known in advance anyways. There's a related question where the accepted answer provides an implementation for simulated multiple dispatch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8595840/4041697 However, the problem with this solution is that (as with the `match`-statement) you'd have to "register" all possible method calls - and you don't have a static guarantee that you have registered all types.

Comment: See my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I remove the method `addLogItem[A <: LogItem] (item: A): Unit` and open up the visibility of the other ones, it works. So in essence, the `LogService` becomes sort of a visitor itself.

```
class LogService {
  def addLogItem(item: LogItemOne) = { println(item.toString) }
  def addLogItem(item: LogItemTwo) = { println(item.toString) }
}
```

Comment: You still need to know the static type of your `LogItem`. Consider the code `val logItem: LogItem = new LogItemOne; (new LogService).addLogItem(logItem)` which will now not compile.